# org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller

Tags: apache-nifi

I am setting up a NiFi 1.7.1 release build cluster of 3 nodes.
I am using 3 other nodes for zookeeper (not using the embedded zk)
Using Java 1.8 build 181

Getting this error when starting Nifi in cluster mode with external zookeeper

Nifi-bootstrap.log

```
2018-08-21 19:58:49,675 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 14956
2018-08-21 19:58:50,156 INFO [NiFi Bootstrap Command Listener] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi Apache NiFi now running and listening for Bootstrap requests on port 44710
2018-08-21 19:59:09,700 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Failed to start web server: Unable to start Flow Controller.
2018-08-21 19:59:09,701 ERROR [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr Shutting down...
2018-08-21 19:59:10,679 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi NiFi never started. Will not restart NiFi
```

Nifi-App.log

```
2018-08-21 19:59:09,222 WARN [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7115d5af{/nifi-api,file:///opt/nifi-1.7.1/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.7.1.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.7.1.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.7.1.war}
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:876)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:839)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:838)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:157)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController' defined in class path resource [nifi-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clusterCoordinator' while setting bean property 'clusterCoordinator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterCoordinator': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterCoordinationProtocolSenderListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'protocolListener' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'protocolListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [null] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type 'null'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:55)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController' defined in class path resource [nifi-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clusterCoordinator' while setting bean property 'clusterCoordinator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterCoordinator': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterCoordinationProtocolSenderListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'protocolListener' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original cause of the exception is `Error creating bean with name 'protocolListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Could not convert argument value of type [null] to required type [int]: ...` Parameter 1 (the *second* parameter) of `protocolListener` is the `clusterNodeProtocolPort`:

```
    <!-- protocol listener -->
    <bean id="protocolListener" class="org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <bean factory-bean="nifiProperties" factory-method="getClusterNodeProtocolThreads"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <bean factory-bean="nifiProperties" factory-method="getClusterNodeProtocolPort"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="protocolServerSocketConfiguration" index="2"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="protocolContext" index="3"/>
    </bean>
```

In your `nifi.properties` file, you should have: `nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=11443` or some other port number. I'm guessing it is blank in your `nifi.properties`. Remember to set it on each node, and ensure the ports do not conflict if they are running on the same machine.

Make sure all your Zookeeper settings are correct on each node as well.

Comment: Hey @andy, you are absolutely right, that value was blank, I set it to 8888 and then I ran into another issue that node1 could not talk to node2 on that port, so I updated the iptables and then all worked like a charm.    Just a quick note to the docs team that they need o mark that field as "required" if the node is clustered,

Comment: Hi Vijay, in the [NiFi Admin Guide -- Basic Cluster Setup](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#clustering), it is specified as required. I have asked one of our docs maintainers to see what we can do to make this clearer for new users. 

_For each Node, the minimum properties to configure are as follows:
...
Under Cluster Node Properties, set the following:
...
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port - Set this to an open port that is higher than 1024 (anything lower requires root)._